# Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: c#, sql, database, nhibernate, orm

I'm having difficulty to figure out NH exception:

> Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row
>   count: 0; expected: 1

My Dal code:

```
 public T Save(T item)
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetSession())
            {
                using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(item);

                    transaction.Commit();

                    return item;
                }
            }
        }
```

My log4net file:

> command 0:UPDATE Metadata_FriendDetails SET UserId = @p0, Email = @p1,
>   Name = @p2 WHERE FriendId = @p3;@p0 =
>   a358ab9d-d481-4bdd-8cb2-18ddc8898c70 [Type: Guid (0)], @p1 =
>   '1@hotmail.com' [Type: String (4000)], @p2 = 'myFriend' [Type: String
>   (4000)], @p3 = 2ea35658-edb1-43e3-b848-e1915d1042df [Type: Guid (0)]
>
> 2011-12-02 13:06:49,750 [Agent: adapter run thread for test
>   'SaveFriendDetails_Test' with id
>   '17016e48-1ff4-4dea-8536-6aa3b24e5fb7'] DEBUG
>   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Closed IDbCommand, open
>   IDbCommands: 0 2011-12-02 13:06:49,751 [Agent: adapter run thread for
>   test 'SaveFriendDetails_Test' with id
>   '17016e48-1ff4-4dea-8536-6aa3b24e5fb7'] ERROR
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not
>   synchronize database state with session
>   NHibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row
>   count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Does anyone see the problem?

TIA

Comment: I think you should write the source of exception with the exception. It will be more helpfull.

Comment: A couple of possiblites, your object is detached and was never actaully created in the databse, so there is no orginal object row to update. Or something has changed a value in the table before your update. I presume that this is a repeatible exeception ? Posting some code snipts on how you are creating, updating, and saving the object would be helpful.

Comment: added.i cannot see why:  NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session NHibernate

Answer (score 33, accepted):

the problem was that on Save I shouldn't supply the id value and on update I must supply it.

Comment: As soon as you are able, be sure and mark this answer as accepted so others will know there is a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You must set the Id object to `null` before saving.

**example:**

```
obj.setId(null);
objectDao.save(obj);
```

Comment: if you have an Integer ID you have to use: obj.setId(0) - so it works. Wasn't working for me, because I had set the Id to -1